# MySQL Drop User Fails for Remote Host

Tags: mysql-5.5, users, remote

We're clearing out some old MySQL users that connected from remote hosts during a database transfer.

Why is this `DROP USER` query failing for the user `asdfasdf_imac4`? I'm logged in as root.

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+------------------+----------------------+
| user             | host                 |
+------------------+----------------------+
| root             | 127.0.0.1            |
| root             | ::1                  |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost            |
| forum            | localhost            |
| root             | localhost            |
| asdfasdf_imac4   | ‘303.303.303.90’     |
| asdfasdf_imac4   | ‘303.303.303.92’     |
+------------------+----------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop user 'asdfasdf_imac4'@'303.303.303.90';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'asdfasdf_imac4'@'303.303.303.90'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen an IP address like that before. Since 303 is an impossible number for an IP address, you should just save yourself the headache and delete both from `mysql.user`

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='asdfasdf_imac4';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**Give it a Try !!!**

Answer (score 1):

I think that might because ‘303.303.303.90’ is a string with single quote, you'd better delete it like this: `drop user "asdfasdf_imac4"@"'303.303.303.90'";`